# css menu image background left

Tags: html, css

I have a menu ul li that I want to put in each li one different image:

```
<ul id="menu">

<li class="home">
<a href="$urlsite/home">home</a>
</li>

<li class="sells">
<a href="$urlsite/sells">Sells</a>
</li>

<li class="message">
<a href="$urlsite/message">Message</a>
</li>

</ul>
```

css

```
#menu {
 position:relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 margin-top:0px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-weight:bold;
}
#menu li {
 list-style: none;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:20px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-bottom:0px;
}
#menu li a {
 margin:0;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.home{
 background-image: url('http://infinitilinens.herokuapp.com/assets/icons/home_blue.png');
 background-size:20px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding-left: 30px;
 display: block;
}
```

My problem is, the HOME ICON (and all others) are not in front of the text link. How can I align the image with the link?
http://jsfiddle.net/954baet0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)

> The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the
>   vertical

```
#menu li {
 list-style: none;
 text-align:left;
 padding-left:20px;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border-bottom:0px;
background-position: 2px center;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/954baet0/20/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a background image as a logo (be aware that it will not be clickable) you could use the [background-position property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp).

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You just add this line of code to your .home:

```
background-position: 0px 11px;
```